# Stacking and placing draggable elements on top without affecting others?

Tags: javascript, css, jquery-ui

I'm fooling around with draggable elements and found myself stuck on the stacking part.

I have three windows that are draggable and when clicked the specific element stacks on top the other two. However the stacking order seem to be "reset" on the other two when a window is clicked. For example if I click on .window1 and .window2 is in the back it ends up on top of .window3.

I'm using javascript with a onmouse z-index property for the stacking. Is there a way to make only the clicked element stack on top without affecting the other two? Any help or pointing in the right direction is welcome, cheers!

HTML:

```
<div class="window1">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="window2">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="window3">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```

My javascript for drag and z-index for stacking:

```
    $( ".window1, .window2, .window3" ).draggable({ handle: ".header" });

    $('.window1, .window2, .window3').on('mousedown', function(event) { 
      $('.window1, .window2, .window3').css('z-index','1');
      $( this ).css('z-index','1000');
    });
```

Comment: This is a mere suggestion to get your task accomplished. The jsPlumb library has some pretty neat functionalities to accomplish this without the need to manually worry about draggable element stacking and z-index concerns. [Check this out](https://jsplumbtoolkit.com)

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Stack](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#option-stack) option to bring the current dragged item to the front without affecting the other items:

```js
$( ".window1, .window2, .window3" ).draggable({ handle: ".header", stack: ".window" });
```

```css
.window1 {
  background-color: orange;
  width: 100px;
}

.window2 {
  background-color: lightgreen;
  width: 100px;
}

.window3 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div class="window window1">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="window window2">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>

<div class="window window3">
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
</div>
```